# How to structure Master Templates and Doc Types in this case?

Tags: umbraco

I need to create a new website on Umbraco (version 4). The website will have a main landing page which will contain 4 links pointing to 4 sets of geographical sub-sites.

In the main master template, I would include all the usual HTML Head stuff with CSS and JS links etc. In the body content, there will be two contentPlaceHolders:

1. The website logo will be on the left with another banner image on the right at the top. This section will be constantly reused in every other page.
2. A placeholder for displaying the 4 links.

My question is: How can I structure the templates and Doc types in Settings in order for the Header logo section to be reused and inherited automatically after the user has uploaded the 2 images once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would specify these properties on a document type at the root of the site, and then using Razor (or XSLT) traverse to the top of the site, get a media picker property, and retrieve the image URL from that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Master Page Control for Convenient & better development approach.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Then After Define placeholder's for each section as your requirement.

```
  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">

    </asp:Content>
```

Here is the example of my umbraco website

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="WebsiteName.Masterpages.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>All One Health</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <link href="/Css/main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Css/custom.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Css/navmenu.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Css/download.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Css/jquery.selectbox.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--<link href="/Css/ie10.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/placeholders.min.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE 8]>
            <link href="/Css/ie8.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
            <link href="/Css/ie9.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <![endif]-->




    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="/Css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <!--  Header Section   -->
        <header class="mobile-header">

            <umbraco:Macro Alias="MobileUtilityNavigation" runat="server" />
            <div class="mobile-header-nav-logo">
                <div class="logo">
                    <umbraco:Macro Alias="Header" runat="server" />
                    <umbraco:Macro Alias="MobileMenuNavigation" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <header class="header">
            <umbraco:Macro Alias="HeaderUtilityNav" runat="server" />
            <div class="header-nav-logo">
                <div class="logo">
                    <umbraco:Macro Alias="Header" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="ghost-logo"></div>
                <umbraco:Macro Alias="HeaderMainNav" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--  Header End   -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SliderContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <!--   Body Section   -->
        <div id="page">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!--  Footer Section  -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="grey">
                <umbraco:Macro Alias="Header" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
                <umbraco:Macro Alias="MobileMainNavigatoin" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
                <umbraco:Macro Alias="MobileUtilityFooterLinks" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
            </div>
            <umbraco:Macro Alias="Footer" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
        </footer>
        <!-- Footer end  -->

        <!--Scrips-->

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/split.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```